# Remove xcode4.2 after installing xcode4.6

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, xcode4.6

In the last step of installing xcode 4.6, it asks if you want to remove previous version xcode 4.2. Unfortunately I forgot to do that because I hit proceed button too soon. The UI hint is not intuitive and I was very quick and not able to recall all the details.  So I have two questions: 1. how do I know if I have previous version xcode4.2 in my Mac? 2. If previous version xcode 4.2 is still in my Mac, how do I remove it.

Comment: Why you want to remove? I have 3 xcode versions installed and enjoying each one :)

Comment: I am afraid it will cause some issues. So in your experience, is there no any issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you have n xcode folders under /Applications, it is there n times
if you only have one it isn't installed

there *may* be some 4.2 specific docs installed ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/Docsets that you can delete...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.2 is installed in the `/Developer` folder at the root of your drive. Xcode 4.3 and beyond are installed in `/Applications` instead. So to uninstall Xcode 4.2, you just need to move the entire `/Developer` folder to the trash.

Easy as that.